# How can I get a reference of the cy object in ngx-cytoscape?

Tags: angular, cytoscape.js

I'm trying to use [ngx-cytoscape](https://github.com/calvinvette/ngx-cytoscape).

I've managed to get it work and the graph appears, but the next step would require getting a reference to the cy object.

There is an example on ngx-cytoscape's GitHub page for adding plugins, but it doesn't say in which file that code snippet should be added to or what else is required to get it work.

Could anyone help with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Demo Component

There is full version of demo component here - https://github.com/calvinvette/ngx-cytoscape/blob/master/cytodemo/cytodemo.component.ts

### getting a reference to the cy object.

You can get the reference by `cy` Object by using the `@ViewChild` in your component and you can get the access of `cy` object from this reference component in `ngAfterViewInit` function.

```
@ViewChild(CytoscapeComponent)
private cytograph: CytoscapeComponent;

ngAfterViewInit() {
      if (this.cytograph.cy) {
        const cyLayer = this.cytograph.cy.cyCanvas();
        const cnv: HTMLCanvasElement = cyLayer.getCanvas();
        const ctx: CanvasRenderingContext2D = cnv.getContext("2d");
        // ...
          this.cytograph.cy.on("render cyCanvas.resize", function(evt, src) {
              // "this" is now "cy" inside this callback function
              cyLayer.resetTransform(ctx);
              cyLayer.clear(ctx);
              ctx.fillStyle = "#ff00ff";
              //ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 100, 100); // Top left corner
              cyLayer.setTransform(ctx);

              const width = cnv.width;
              const height = cnv.height;
              const data = Array(width * height);

              // Draw model elements
              this.nodes().forEach(function(node) {
                  const pos = node.position();
                  // Do something with canvas at or around the node's position
                  ctx.fillRect(pos.x - 25, pos.y - 25, 50, 50); // At node position (bisection point of 50x50 rectangle)
              });
          });
      }
      // ...
  }
```

Comment: Should this example code be put in the component that contains the CytoscapeComponent, which looks the same as CytoscapeDemoComponent? I've tried this way, but there is no cy reference.

Comment: Yes, you should put answered code into the component which contains `CytoscapeComponent`. So that you can access to through `@ViewChild`. You must be able to access the `cy` reference from the `CytoscapeComponent`. If you ara not able to access it then check if you have imported the `CytoscapeComponent` from the right module. If that is also correct then have quick glance at `CytoscapeComponent`  code. It must be having reference of `cy`.

Comment: OK, got it. I had to import { CytoscapeComponent } from "ngx-cytoscape" and not it works. Thanks!